# how do I make the default git commit message use CRLF line endings

Tags: git

The default git commit message includes the following:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch testNotepad
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   foo.txt
```

I have notepad setup as my default editor in git. This message is displayed as a single line due to the fact that line endings are not CRLF. I would like to change this. How can this be done?

Comment: Notepad - you mean *the* Windows Notepad? Have you considered using an actual editor?

Comment: @sleske yes the windows notepad. I should be able to use whatever editor I would like. I like notepad. If the system is not broken in some way, there should be an answer for this.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is currently possible.  Doesn't mean "the system is broken in some way".  It just means Git can support/not support whatever line-endings it likes.  If indeed this can't be done then you'll just have to change editors, or request/code the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git does not support this directly.  You will need to use an editor that can handle Unix-style line endings (`\n`).

However, if your editor of choice does not support this, you can instead set your editor to a proxy that will convert the line endings to Windows-style (`\r\n`), invoke your editor, then convert the line endings to Unix-style (`\n`) for git.

[GitPad](https://github.com/github/gitpad) is the best example of an editor proxy that can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

This feature to support notepad may have been added since this question was asked. I was able to repro using version 2.16.1.windows.4.

Opens notepad with no line returns showing:

```
git config --global core.editor "notepad.exe"
```

However using this instead worked for me:

```
git config --global core.editor "notepad"
```

Just a matter of leaving the .exe off of the end.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried setting `core.autocrlf` to `true`?

Something like:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: No; `core.autocrlf` only affects how checkout writes text files to the working directory.